# IVP computer code stuff

Tags: numerical-methods, maple

I need help with this following problem:

> Write maple code to solve numerically the initial value problem
>
> $\frac{dy}{dt} = g(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(x) dx$ and $y(0)=0$.
>
> a) Use numerical integration on $f$ to define $g$ and a numerical
>   differential equation solver of your choice.
>
> b) Find and graph numerical solutions for $f(x)=x$ and
>   $f(x)=exp(-x^2)$ on $0\leq t\leq 10$.
>
> c) Compare the solution for $f(x)=x$ with the exact solution
>   $y(t)=\frac{t^3}{6}$

I don't really even know where to begin.
.

Comment: I need to solve this thing within an hr!

Comment: Use a built in function for DE solving in Maple such as Newton's method: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/Calculus1/NewtonsMethod or you could use Maple's built in Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: I solved this exact same problem on MaplePrimes last week. Look up the Answer there. You can find it in Carl Love's Answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a differential equation, $y'(t) = g(t)$ with initial condition $y(0) = 0$. Use a numerical differential equation solver (pick any from Maple or implement your own), and plug in the function $g$, which is also numerically computed as $g(t) = \int_0^t f(x)dx$ (use numerical integration to compute the integral).

Once the code is done, plug in $f_1(x) = x$ and $f_2(x) = e^{-x^2}$ on $t \in [0,10]$ to generate $g_1, g_2$ via numerical integration and $y_1, y_2$ via numerical ODE solution.

Then solve the problem analytically ($g_1(t) = \int_0^t xdx = t^2/2$ so what is $y_1(t)$ - can you deduce it from the differential equation?) and compare the analytic solution to the numerical one you got.

Comment: "Once the code is done"?? Numerical integration and numerical differential equation solving cannot proceed until the function is specified, and the integration also requires the endpoint.

Comment: @CarlLove you take the function pointer as an input into the procedure.